# Counting Number of Children in Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to count how many child nodes a particular node contains on my database

I am planning on having many users, and want to the expierence to be as fast as possible, so I know I don't want to download the parent node and count

I've thought of simply having a counter field stored, and everytime a user does something to add to that parent also incriment that value.. however I am pretty inexpierenced with this and am worried
that somehow two users adding something at the same time or so will cause that value to be incorrect..which from my reading is whata transaction operation is create for

I remeber when I used to use Parse a while ago, there was something called CloudCode that would constantly run on the server and in particular I would use it for maintence operations on the database
Would running a transaction operation be the solution here? Currious to hear how others handle stuff like this.. do they have some sort of monitering server maintaining it

Comment: _As fast as possible.._ Don't waste your life with micro optimizations (unless you're working in Facebook and every millisecond saves you millions of dollars), latency is and always will be the slowest part, data just can't move faster than light.

Comment: @Solo good point haha. But there still has to be a faster/better solution than downloading large sets of data haha.. I guess not nescarily "as fast as possible"s

Comment: if you only plan having the data means you do not have them yet. so you should consider a counter incrementing with each new user registration so you do not need to bother with counting millions of users every time you want to now exact number.